# How to solve rat riddle in Shido's palace?

Tags: persona-5

I'm trying to get my second letter in *Shido's palace*. At the restaurant, I took an elevator to *Mid Starboard Hallway*.

Here, one turns into a rat within grey rooms with activated statues.

I know that one as a rat can go through vents (small, white paths) and that there's a switch in one room ( yellow check mark) that turns them off.

Yet since all the doors are locked (yellow lock symbols) I cannot proceed to the other areas (all in red).

I'm stuck here, going in circles ad nauseam and am unsure how to open those locked doors.

Can I find the solution here or do I have to go somewhere else first? How to get the doors unlocked.

[image: map of mid Starboard hallways with all locked doors marked]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map doesn't show all the vents right away but you have to locate them. (Similar you only see the locked door symbols once you try to open one.)

If you are stuck in any of the rat riddle stages, you have to scout the grey rooms for further vents, or flip the switch to activate the statues in other rooms.

In your particular case, the big grey room having all the enemies, there's another vent (cursor):

[image: Location of unlocated vent, area marked cyan]

If one goes through there, one can unlock top doors, and from there one hit the switch and one is now able to unlock all the other doors on this level.